# "Cannot find type" while creating a dependency graph in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a solution that consists of several projects. When I try to create a dependency graph (under the Architecture menu), I get this error:

> Cannot find type *[name of a perfectly good interface]* in module *[name of a dll]*.dll

I've checked that this type exists in the DLL, and other DLLs use it without a problem. Everything in my solution works fine except for the dependency graph creation. I've tried cleaning up and rebuilding multiple times, but nothing helps.

Has anyone encountered anything like this?

**EDIT:** I unloaded some of the projects, namely test projects, and then it worked.

Comment: Is the interface public?

Comment: @WiseGuyEh, yep, it's public, and other assemblies are using it without any problem.

Comment: Having exactly the same issue with a very simple interface :( any luck?